# Expand WP7 content element on tap

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any way or are there any elements in WP7 which could be expanded on tap? For example if I'm using a ItemViewModel I'd like to show only the content of `LineOne` and when that is tapped I want to show the content of `LineTwo`.

I don't necessarily need to do this with a ItemViewModel. For example the hidden content could also be buttons that appear instead of a line of text.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into the `ExpanderView` from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/)? It allows you to have a tap-to-expand template and a standard template. There's a reasonable overview of it available at [Windowsphonegeek](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Toolkit-ExpanderView-in-depth-Part1-key-concepts-and-API)